# Naming [most] of the 7 nations within ה and י

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, parashat-noach

When listing the families of the 12 tribes, the Torah wraps the names between ה and י. [Rashi brings Yalkut Shimoni (Num 26,5)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.26.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Nikkud&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.26.5.1&lang2=bi):

> **משפחת החנכי**. לְפִי שֶׁהָיוּ הָאֻמּוֹת מְבַזִּין אוֹתָם ..., לְפִיכָךְ הִטִּיל הַקָּבָּ"ה שְׁמוֹ עֲלֵיהֶם — **ה"א מִצַּד זֶה וְיוֹ"ד מִצַּד זֶה — לוֹמַר, מֵעִיד אֲנִי עֲלֵיהֶם שֶׁהֵם בְּנֵי אֲבוֹתֵיהֶם**, וְזֶה הוּא שֶׁמְּפֹרָשׁ עַל יְדֵי דָוִד "שִׁבְטֵי יָהּ עֵדוּת לְיִשְׂרָאֵל" — הַשֵּׁם הַזֶּה מֵעִיד עֲלֵיהֶם לְשִׁבְטֵיהֶם, לְפִיכָךְ בְּכֻלָּם כָּתַב הַחֲנֹכִי, הַפַּלֻּאִי וכו'
>
> Because the heathen nations spoke slightingly of Israel... On this account the Holy One, blessed be He, set His name upon them: the letter ה on one side of their name and the letter י on the other side (חנכיה), to intimate: I bear testimony for them that they are the sons of their reputed fathers (and not of the Egyptians)

Interestingly the very same pattern is used for the names of the 7 nations, the descendants of Kenaan ([Gen 10,15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.10.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וּכְנַעַן יָלַד אֶת־צִידֹן בְּכֹרוֹ וְאֶת־חֵת׃ וְאֶת־**הַיְבוּסִי** וְאֶת־**הָאֱמֹרִי** וְאֵת **הַגִּרְגָּשִׁי**׃וְאֶת־**הַחִוִּי** וְאֶת־**הַעַרְקִי** וְאֶת־**הַסִּינִי**׃ וְאֶת־הָאַרְוָדִי וְאֶת־**הַצְּמָרִי** וְאֶת־**הַחֲמָתִי** וְאַחַר נָפֹצוּ מִשְׁפְּחוֹת **הַכְּנַעֲנִי**׃

(Well, not "exactly" the 7 nations but most). THe other names of Yefet and Shem descendants are written normally, like "וְאַרְפַּכְשַׁד יָלַד אֶת־שָׁלַח וְשֶׁלַח יָלַד אֶת־עֵבֶר׃ "

What could be a reason for that similarity?

Comment: Maybe their names actually began with a ה and/or ended with a י? I can’t say that for כנען, but how do you know that’s not the case for the others (especially אמורי גרגשי חוי etc. - the ones we know end in a י at least)?

Comment: Perhaps since there was a mitzva upon Israel regarding these nations in particular, it was necessary to have some confirmation that these were indeed from the nation in question...

Answer (score 4):

Excellent question! Sifsei Chachamim there asks it, and answers that the Midrash is only coming to answer why it repeats their names with a hey and yud afterwards (e.g. חנוך משפחת החנוכי), but if it is just the nation/family name (e.g. העמלקי) the rule of the Midrash does not apply:

> ואם תאמר הא גבי עכו״ם גם כן כתיב הכי דכתיב וירד העמלקי והכנעני. ויש לומר אי הוה כתיב כאן בני ראובן משפחת החנוכי ולא כתיב חנוך לא היה קשה מידי כמו גבי העמלקי אבל עכשיו דכתיב בני ראובן חנוך משפחת החנוכי קשה למה הטיל ה״א מצד זה ויו״ד מצד זה‏